# Deployed node js socket server in cloud run. But cannot connect through remote client 302 error

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-run, node.js-connect

What i have done so far

1.Deploy node.js in cloud run as a service(web socket server)
2. Used cloud run service url(https://). just replaced https with Ws://
3. With postman client it worked fine. Flutter client also working fine
4. But cannot connect with any other client(online testing, any Arduino device)

Arduino client throughs 302 error

anybody help out

As a begginner , may be i dont know the approach

solution for the above problem and approach